# Ubuntu 12.04 "connecting" for 30 seconds, then gives up and says I'm disconnected

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, wired

I'm completely new to Linux, have a Gateway LT40 netbook running Ubuntu 12.04. I can't get it to connect to the internet at all, wired or wireless. It says "connecting, connecting..." for 30 seconds then says I'm disconnected. Any ideas on what could be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: @WildMan I can't connect to the internet, how can I download anything? I tried putting it in anyway, and it said "unable to resolve host address 'dl.dropbox.com'"

Comment: Follow the directions in this link to run the script without internet. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385#post12350385

Comment: @WildMan here's the wireless info I got [Wireless Info](http://pastebin.com/8PmNVR1n)

Comment: Please go into network manger and remove all wireless connections, then reset your router and after the router comes back on line reboot your computer then click on network manager and see if your network is listed and if you can connect to it.

Comment: The network was listed but I wasn't able to connect to it. Just to clarify, when you say network manager do you mean the orange icon in system settings that says "network?" There's also a network tools, but no network manager.

Comment: I mean go to the top right corner of the screen click on the internet icon remove all wireless connections then reboot. When you reboot go back to top right corner of the screen and make sure networking and wireless are enabled after you reset your router.

Comment: It didn't work, here's a step by step of what I'm doing: 1. Remove all wireless connections from the network manager (disconnect, then edit connections and delete my network)  2. Reset the router (reset button is broken so I unplug and plug it back in)  3. Reboot  4. Connect to network, get prompted for password and type it in  5. cry (yes, wireless is enabled, but I'm still having the same problem)

Comment: What exactly did you do when you say "then edit connections"?

Comment: Well, the network manager (I'm assuming you mean the wi-fi icon on the top right-hand corner) doesn't offer an option to "remove" a connection, only disconnect from it. At the bottom there's an option to edit connections, which opens a dialog box that lists all the networks you've used. I delete the network from there so that it's forgotten and doesn't try to automatically connect when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

a little window will open enter your user password then remove:

```
blacklist brcmsmac

blacklist bcma
```

from the blacklist file that opens then save gedit and close.

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo modprobe bcma

sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

If it does not connect do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

There are 22 wireless networks in your area and that makes it very difficult for network manager to connect to one.

Comment: First option didn't work. Second option gave me a window titled "configuring resolvconf," but then I can't do anything. `the resolvconf package contains the infrastructure required for dynamic updating of the resolver configuration file...the presence of resolvconf can affect the behavior of other programs, so it should not be left installed if unconfigured` Then I can't close the terminal because it's apparently still running.

Comment: I did them both and they did not work, but I had not rebooted. It's fixed now, thank you very much!

Comment: If it is working please accept the answer so everyone will benefit. Thanks